# who has the mv_BlueFox_driver in ROS?

Tags: ros, driver, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo, everybody !

i have a mvBlueFox camera Type 105C, i want to with this camera do the imageprocessing in Linux Ubuntu.
there are driver for the Linux, but how could i do it in ROS driver ?
Or who has the ros driver for this camera, could you share me ?

thanks a lot.
Qiuyue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49852/who-has-the-mv_bluefox_driver-in-ros-?/) by [Wang123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3658/wang123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We wrote a wrapping driver around an old MVImpact library.

https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_camera_drivers/tree/master/mv_bluefox_driver

It seems to be broken now. We have to fix it. If you find the bugs, please let me know.

Carlos

---

Originally posted by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) with karma: 347 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2